# Replace buttons with image in PHP code

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to display images in place of buttons for various activities like Edit Record, Delete Record, Download, Save, Reset. I am able to show the image but the result is very output is looks very childish and nonprofessional. Actually images are coming on button as shown in image 
[image]

But I want image to display like this

[image]
Here is the code which gives the 1st image output.

```
<tr style="background-color: rgb(253, 253, 183); color: rgb(42, 16, 179);font-size: 13px;" >
<td><?php echo $row->eq_application_no; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->eq_class; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->eq_name;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->mid_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->eq_sex; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->father_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->eq_dob; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->age.",".$row->month.",".$row->day;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->scat_id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->parent_cate_id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->no_of_transfer;?></td>
<td><?php echo $tc_case; ?></td>
<td><?php echo$row->last_school_type; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->eq_prv_acdmic;?></td>
<td><?php if($row->kv_tc_date=="1970-01-01"){echo "-";}else{echo $row->kv_tc_date;}?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->kv_tc_no;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->last_class_cgpa;?></td>
<!--value="Edit"-->
<td><input type="button" id="<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>"  onclick="edit_record(<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>)" style="background-image:url(images/edit24.png);width:24px;height:24px;"></td><td>
<!--value="Delete"-->
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>"  onclick="delete_record(<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>)" style="background-image:url(images/delete24.png);width:24px;height:24px;" ></td><td><?php
if($eligible=="Y")
{?><input type="checkbox" class="app" name="app[]" d="
<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>" value="<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>">
<?php }
else
{
echo"-";
}
?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add image directly then:

```
<img src="images/delete24.png" id="<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>"  onclick="delete_record(<?php echo $row->es_enquiryid;?>)" style="cursor:pointer;width:24px;height:24px;" />
```